# Clear python shell within script

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to create a utility program, but after the user types in the passcode and goes to the main menu, the passcode is still there and is show right above it. I asked this question before, but users gave me a command instead of something the script does for you. I was wondering if there is something I can type into my script that can clear the python shell without having to directly type it into the shell.

Comment: why do you show the passcode? even if you clear the screen it will be visible while typed...

Comment: if people gave you a command, can't you use that command with `os.system` to clear it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass) to read passwords without echoing them, that's the reccomended way of reading passwords safely.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux:

```
import os
os.system("clear")
```

if you are using windows:

```
import os
os.system('CLS')
```

Note: you should really not do something like this with passcodes for security reasons, but this does clear the shell

Comment: When I use it, it only restarts it.It doesn't erase it for me.

Comment: What system do you use? I just updated because I only included the Linux/mac terminal approach, if you are using windows try that